# Перевод из 10 сс в 16 сс

Tags: c

Как можно перевести число из десятичной системы счисления в шестнадцатеричную?

Comment: Числа (и целые и с плавающей точкой) так или иначе хранятся в бинарном виде.

Comment: Если уж задаете вопрос, то нужно его задавать корректно. В каком виде задано исходное значение? В каком виде вы хотите получить новое значение? Диапазоны чисел?

Comment: У меня есть ASCII код символа в десятичном виде, мне нужно в шестнадцатеричном

Comment: @Tommy что вы имеете в виду? К примеру, 65 это ascii код для `'A'` в hex это 41. Какой тип ввода, какой желаемый тип результата? `int c = 'A'`; char h[3]={0}; tohex(c, h, sizeof h - 1);`   -> `h[0] == '4' && h[1] == '1'`. Обновите ваш вопрос. Нажмите [edit].

Comment: В своей программе я считываю символ, получаю его десятичный ASCII код и мне нужен шестнадцатеричный.

Comment: @Tommy Опять за рыбу гроши... Вам нужна 1. строка из двух hex-символов, 2. вывести их на экран, 3. какое-то иное представление?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*В своей программе я считываю символ, получаю его десятичный ASCII код и мне нужен шестнадцатеричный.*

Считаем, что у вас есть

```
unsigned char ascii;
```

Ясно, что он в диапазоне 0-255, и вы хотите получить строковое шестнадцатеричное представление. Очевидно, что оно будет состоять из 2 шестнацатеричных цифр.

Запишем в C-строку

```
char hex[3];
```

Очевидно, что первый символ получается из `ascii/16`, т.е.

```
hex[0] = hex_digit(ascii/16);
```

а второй - `ascii%16`:

```
hex[1] = hex_digit(ascii%16);
```

Ну и, конечно,

```
hex[2] = 0;
```

Осталось записать шестнадцатеричный символ со значением от 0 до 15. Опять же несложно:

```
char hex_digit(int code) 
{
    return (code < 10) ? '0' + code : 'a' + code - 10;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

[printf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) - может форматировать в основные базисы

```
num = 250;
printf("dec - %d, hex - %x",num , num);
```

Comment: Это распечатка, а перевод пользовательского ввода чуть сложнее.

Comment: на то есть scanf